# Haskell ExtendedDefaultRules. Changing defaults?

Tags: mongodb, haskell

I work with mongodb and construct a lot of bson types like this.

```
[ "group"  =: "default" , "views" =: 0 ]
```

Specifying the exact types gets really annoying.
I have to construct it like this unless it can be deducted.

```
[ "group"  =: ("default" :: Text) , "views" =: (1 :: Int) ]
```

So giving the `{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}` pragma fixes it but not to the desirable types. It defaults to Integer which is not good for performance reasons and to String which is not good for consistency reasons.

Is it possible to change the defaults and make it default to say Int and Text without qualifying the types manually all the time?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `default (Int, Double)` near the top of your source file?  No extensions needed.  This defaulting only works for Integral and Floating types.  For Text, you might be able to use OverloadedStrings, but I suspect you are already.

Answer (score 2):

With OverloadedStrings, you can use `default (Int, Text)`

Comment: in addition to {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}, and default (Int, Text) you also need {-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-} as implied by the previous message